# Incorrect TS error in defineProps with vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-script-setup

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue';

type Props = {
  duration?: '0'|'0.5'|'1'|'1.5'|'2'|'2.5'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'10',
//^^^^^^^^^ ESLint: Prop 'duration' requires default value to be set.(vue/require-default-prop)
  initialAnimation?: boolean,
  additionalAnimateClasses?: string
};

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Argument type DefineProps<Props, BooleanKey<Props>> is not assignable to parameter type DefineProps<Readonly<Props> & {readonly initialAnimation: boolean}, keyof Readonly<Props> & {readonly initialAnimation: boolean}> 
  initialAnimation: true,
  additionalAnimateClasses: ''
});
```

Why this erros are showing? My intension is to set default value for some of the optional props

Comment: I think ESLint is wrong here.  You can always disable the rule for the specific line, or provide `duration: undefined` fo the default value within the `withDefaults` macro to make ESLint happy

Comment: Thank you @yoduh, I can disable it but wanted a solution so EsLint doesn't complains & the 2nd error from TS